# Spring Boot websocket connection timing out

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

The problem I am having is that whenever I try to connect to my spring boot application from an external computer on the same LAN, my WebSocket connection times out. I should also ask if spring boot is the right tool in order to only host my app server. My actual webpage will be hosted from a different machine and this could partially be the problem.

This is what my Java code looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class CinderApp implements WebSocketConfigurer {

final static String DEFAULT_APP_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080";

@Bean
public MessageHandler callHandler() {
    return new MessageHandler();
}

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(callHandler(), "/call");
}
```

And on the browser client end I have the javascript:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + "192.168.1.112:8080" + '/call');
```

Where 192.168.1.112 is the ip spring boot application server.

This connection fails after the timeout period and returns a fault. I would just like to know how I can establish a websocket connection with the spring boot app server from an external ip browser(on the same LAN).

Comment: do you manage to connect from the same computer ? if so, can you ping your computer from the client ? maybe you computer's firewall is blocking incoming connections ?

Comment: That was it, thanks.